# mysql call tables mp3s,artists,tags

Tags: php, mysql, relation

mp3s

```
ID 
Title 
Description
```

tags

```
ID
Title
```

artists

```
ID
Title
```

artist_relations

```
mp3ID //call to mp3s.ID
artistID // call to artists.ID
```

tag_relations

```
mp3ID //call to mp3s.ID
tagID // call to tags.ID
```

I need this result in one query:

```
row1 : mp3ID | mp3Title | mp3Description | tag1,tag2,tag3 | artist1
row2 : mp3ID | mp3Title | mp3Description | tag20,tag22    | artist8,artist5
...
```

Comment: Looks like you can't have tags in results because tags tables does not relate to any of other tables.

Comment: tag_relations called 'mp3s' and tags

Comment: the expected result for the tags will be rows and i am not sure if you can concatenate a column in multi rows result into 1 col in 1 row using 1 qry, however, logically i am wondaring how could the same MP3 with the same MP3ID be connected to more than one artiest? i mean the song could be performed by more than 1 artiest but then it will not be the same mp3id right? EDIT: unless its a multi artiest song :)

Comment: my english is not good :( please help me

Comment: some songs have more than one artist or tag

Comment: Hey, @progrenalin, check out my suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    mp3.ID as mp3id, 
    mp3.title as mp3title, 
    mp3.description as mp3description, 
    group_concat(distinct artist.title) as artists, 
    group_concat(distinct tag.title) as tags 
from mp3s as mp3 
left join artist_relations as ar 
    on ar.MP3ID = mp3.ID 
left join artists artist 
    on ar.ARTISTID = artist.ID 
left join tag_relations as tr 
    on tr.MP3ID = mp3.ID 
left join tags as tag 
    on tag.ID = tr.TAGID 
group by mp3.ID
```

And I tried to reproduce on expecially created db with structure you described and got this result:

| mp3_id | mp3_title | mp3_description | artists                            | tags  |

|      1 | first     | first one       | zemfira,splean                     | a,b   |

|      2 | second    | second one      | leningrad,deep purple,led zeppelin | c,d,e |